# Windows - C++, best way to constantly run program?

Tags: c++, windows, cursor, mouse

I'm making a simple program that wraps the mouse cursor around my monitors, so it constantly needs to check the position of the mouse cursor to know whether it should change the mouse position. I have just been using a while(1) loop but this seems too intensive, I'm using over 25% of my CPU with this simple program, is there another way.

Comment: Thanks, I just adding Sleep(17) to my while loop so it should run every 17ms (since my monitors are 60hz that update every 16.667ms. CPU utilization for the program is now 0% in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Flawed assumption. Your program should run on every mouse move message. The term you'll want to google is "Hook mouse".